# Object publication to ensure thread-safety

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am reading about `publication` objects to ensure thread-safety.
(This is described in book `Concurrency in Practice - Brian Goetz`.
But I feel that I don't understand `publication` of object correctly.

I think that: if object is correctly published then is ready to be used by multiple thread.

How do you understand `publication` of object ?

Any easy/short explanation is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Publication** simply means making the object visible/available to other objects in the system. By the time your object's constructor returns, all of its state should be correctly initialized so that it's ready for use.

(Note that some frameworks will apply post-construction processing to managed objects; in this case, the object's state should be stable before returning from `@PostConstruct`.)

Comment: Slight nit, it's actually not about when the constructor returns, but rather when another thread can read a variable that stores the object's reference. If it were just about constructor returning, there'd be nothing to safe publication.